# Several mentions of 'org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException' in the log file

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application in production. For a particular day, in a span of 6 minutes, I noticed 44 mentions of RequestRejectedException. I don't see it on any other day. Is it something I have to worry about?

```
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The 
request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious 
String "//"

The request was rejected because the HTTP method "KLLYRC" was not included 
within the list of allowed HTTP methods [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, 
PATCH, PUT]

The request was rejected because the HTTP method "TRACE" was not included 
within the list of allowed HTTP methods [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, 
PATCH, PUT]

The request was rejected because the HTTP method "TRACK" was not included 
within the list of allowed HTTP methods [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, 
PATCH, PUT]

The request was rejected because the HTTP method "SEARCH" was not included 
within the list of allowed HTTP methods [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, 
PATCH, PUT]

The request was rejected because the HTTP method "PROPFIND" was not 
included within the list of allowed HTTP methods [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, 
OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT]

The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious 
String "%2e"

The request was rejected because the HTTP method "NESSUS" was not included 
within the list of allowed HTTP methods [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, 
PATCH, PUT]
```

Should I take some actions to be more prepared if these are some kind of attack?